# Static front page with excerpt

Tags: pages, excerpt, frontpage

I'm currently developping a theme for WordPress, and I have run into a little issue.
I have to display some text as well as a "latest articles" list on the front page. I have the front page set to **Static** in the settings, and the page which is used as a front page contains the text I want to display. All okay here, text displays correctly.

The problem is, I only want to display an excerpt of this text on the front page, while still allowing visitors to click on the "Read more" button to read the full text. WordPress doesn't allow that, though : the page set to *front page* doesn't behave like the others, and it is now only accessible by the front page itself.

Is there a way to have 2 links pointing to the same page?

- The first one pointing to the front page (e.g. http://mydomain.com/), displaying only the excerpt inside the front page template
- The second one pointing to the classic page address (e.g. http://mydomain.com/?p=14), displaying the full page content like any other page

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin should help you. It ads the Excerpt Meta box to the Edit Page:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-excerpts-for-wordpress-three/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used a rather hacky jQuery approach to hide the non-excerpt content until the visitor clicks on the button, but I'll look into your way.